# Written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the Exists

Tags: sql, ms-access

The query below is supposed to pull records for fields with the max date.

I am getting an error

> You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using EXISTS reserved word in the Main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one column.

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE (((([Project_Name], [Date])) IN (SELECT Project_Name, MAX(Date) 
                                       FROM TableName 
                                       GROUP BY Project)));
```

Comment: It would help to know the design of the table. Specifically, how project and project_name relate to each other. Are there different project_names listed under each project and you want the most recent project_name for each project?

Comment: Why without using `EXISTS`? What's wrong with using `EXISTS`?

Comment: EXISTS doesn't work in Access

Comment: Your subquery can't work because you do GROUP BY Project and you SELECT Project_Name.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably thinking of a nested subquery used as a table, like the below:

```
select a.*, b.1, b.2
from FirstTable A
join (Select Id, firstcolumn as 1, secondcolumn as 2
  from SecondTable) B on b.ID = a.ID
```

Works pretty much like a regular join except you are using a subquery. Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableName A 
INNER JOIN (select Project_Name, max(Date) MaxDate
            from TableName 
            group by Project) B
ON  A.[Project_Name] = B.[Project_Name]
AND A.[Date] = B.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

A version using EXISTS() looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName AS A
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT B.Project_Name, MAX( B.Date ) AS MaxDate
        FROM TableName AS B
        GROUP BY B.Project_Name ) AS C
    WHERE C.Project_Name = A.Project_Name AND C.MaxDate = A.Date
);
```

Although I have the feeling this will have poorer performance than a JOIN because the GROUP BY statement might have to be executed for each record and each call to the EXISTS() function...